# To Solve A Sudoku with Grid Size More Than 9*9 Using Multi-threading Parallel Execution

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I'm working on a project where I've to solve a Sudoku puzzle N^2*N^2
 where N less than equals 20.

I've written a single threaded Sudoku solver which works fine with puzzles having N's value 5 but if I increase the N's value like N=10 or 20 the code become unresponsive. I also tried using thread-pool (java.concurrent) and assign `N^2` number of thread to execute parallel. But it's not working can any one give me any solution to this which can improve the performance.

Here's my single threaded approach:

```
public class SUDOKU {

    public static int[][] grid;

    public boolean solveSUDOKU() {
        int row;
        int col;
        int[] blankCell = findBlankLocation();
        row = blankCell[0];
        col = blankCell[1];
        if (row == -1) {
            // means will have filled the grid, return;
            return true;
        }
        // we need to fill grid[row][col] cell
        for (int i = 1; i <= grid.length; i++) {
            // check if number i is safe for grid[row][col] cell
            if (isSafe(row, col, i)) {
                // means its safe to fill the number
                grid[row][col] = i;
                // fill the rest of the grid
                if (solveSUDOKU()) {
                    return true;
                }
                // if we are here that means current selection of number didnt
                // work, revert back the changes
                grid[row][col] = 0;
            }
        }
        return false; // This will cause the backtracking
    }

    public boolean isSafe(int row, int col, int n) {
        // we need to check row contains number n OR
        // Column contains number n OR
        // Block in which cell appears contains number n
        // If Any of the above statement is true, return false
        if (!UsedInRow(row, n)
                && !UsedInColumn(col, n)
                && !UsedInBox((int) (row - row % Math.sqrt(grid.length)),
                        (int) (col - col % Math.sqrt(grid.length)), n)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // check if n not in particular row
    public boolean UsedInRow(int row, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            if (grid[row][i] == n) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // check if n not in particular column
    public boolean UsedInColumn(int col, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            if (grid[i][col] == n) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // check if n not in particular box
    public boolean UsedInBox(int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.sqrt(grid.length); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Math.sqrt(grid.length); j++) {
                if (grid[i + boxStartRow][j + boxStartCol] == n) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int[] findBlankLocation() {
        int[] cell = new int[2]; // cell[0]-row cell[1] -column
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
                if (grid[i][j] == 0) {
                    cell[0] = i;
                    cell[1] = j;
                    return cell;
                }
            }
        }
        cell[0] = -1;
        cell[1] = -1;
        return cell; // means grid is full
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            if (row % Math.sqrt(grid.length) == 0) {
                System.out.println(); // for more readability
            }
            for (int col = 0; col < grid.length; col++) {
                if (col % Math.sqrt(grid.length) == 0) {
                    System.out.print(" "); // for more readability
                }
                System.out.print(grid[row][col] + " ");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        grid = new int[][]{
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
        SUDOKU s = new SUDOKU();
        if (s.solveSUDOKU()) {
            s.print();
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO SOLUTION");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Unless you have hundreds of cores, forget multithreading as it can give you a small factor only. Using a smarter algorithm may give you much more for less work. +++ I guess that simply finding places which allow a single value and filling them immediately could help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept. Two quick questions: A) mind telling me how you progressed on your problem? B) in case that one upvote isn't from your side; is there anything I could do to make my answer upvote-worty from your side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are not that simple. You don't throw "parallel" and "more threads" at a problem and you magically improve performance.

In your case, you have a **huge** search tree to cover. Meaning: your methods might be called **many millions** of times.

So the first thing to do: **understand** what your code is doing.

Meaning: you can start with simple print statements; or by adding "invocation counters". Or, if lookout for existing *profiling* tools that help you understand in **which** parts your program spends most of its time. And then you start looking into ways to optimize.

A first, obvious candidate: you are computing

```
Math.sqrt(grid.length)
```

like in 3 or 5 different places. That is a rather **expensive** solution.  The sqrt() could **easily** be avoided (by computing the value once and putting it into a constant that all other code will be using). It might also be worth looking into the modulo computation (although that one might be harder to get rid of).

And beyond that: in order to **parallelize** your code, you have to understand how that code is working its data. You see, you can't just go for n threads working the **same** single array of numbers. Because all of a sudden you have to worry about **consistency**; you can't have one thread overwrite content while another one is reading it.

So, the essential answer is:

- understand your code in the single-thread scenario
- optimize your single-thread solution, by avoiding anything that is too expensive

And then; when you actually understand what your code is doing; and you are still not happy; then you might be looking into throwing "more threads" at your problem. But even then: keep in mind that threads do not come for free. There is a significant overhead in creating and switching between them. For purely CPU-intensive operations having more threads will not help much.

Threads help with higher throughput when you have a lot of IO operations (and threads waiting for data to be read from IO).